# trending tag in a week like twitter wont work

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a hit list like twitter trending hashtags in one week. The following code working for just `1 DAY` but i want to change it `1 WEEK` how can i do that. I still tryed to change it `INTERVAL 1 WEEK` but didn't worked. Anyone can help me here ?

```
$query = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(created) > CURRENT_DATE AND FROM_UNIXTIME(created) < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND Tag != ''") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
```

Comment: You're selecting posts that were "created" after the current time, that doesn't sound correct.

Comment: Not working means?

Comment: @juergend not working means not have any result if i use INTERVAL 1 WEEK. Normal the question query for INTERVAL 1 DAY is resulting 5 tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are select the interval in wrong way  )
if you want a week for tomorrow and a week use (week o 7 day

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM posts 
  WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(created) > CURRENT_DATE 
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(created) < (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) 
  AND Tag != ''

  SELECT * 
  FROM posts 
  WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(created) > CURRENT_DATE 
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(created) < (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 7 DAY ) 
  AND Tag != ''
```

Otherwise if you want select a week before  use

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM posts 
  WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(created) > (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
  AND   FROM_UNIXTIME(created) <= CURRENT_DATE 
  AND Tag != ''
```

But if the date is already in datetime format use

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE created > CURRENT_DATE 
AND created < (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 7 DAY ) 
AND Tag != ''
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But this code is not worked: `SELECT * 
  FROM posts 
  WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(created) > CURRENT_DATE 
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(created) < (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) 
  AND Tag != ''`

Comment: Could you tell me the data type of the field created .. and waht do you mean with not worked .. error? ...wrong result? ...no error and no result?

Comment: Any way i have update  the answer with a new suggestion